# Why Progress Dialog is not open while clicking on Submit Button

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have set the IP of Ethernet. here i am creating the file on a specific path and run the code of IP set i.e.,sudo.

Everything works well but It is not showing the progress dialog box on the click of the submit button but all other functions mentioned in the `setOnClickListener` are working properly.

Can anybody help me.

```
 submt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validationIP();
            if (var == true) {
                ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(Third_Ethernet_Layout.this);
                progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
                progressdialog.show();
                progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                try {
                    File file = new File(filepath);
                    file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                write();
                sudo(ipfetch, netmaskfetch, gatewayfetch, dns1fetch, dns2fetch);
                progressdialog.dismiss();
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(Third_Ethernet_Layout.this, "Ethernet IP Change Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: how to use here async task....can u please explain it

Comment: It is showing progress dialog, just comment your dismiss line

Comment: i have tried but its not working .....#Attiq_ur_Rehman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `progressdialog.dismiss();` so that progressdialog is dismissed.
You should user asunc Task for it

```
private class AsyncAboutUs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(Third_Ethernet_Layout.this);
                progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
                progressdialog.show();
                progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... strings) {
           try {
                    File file = new File(filepath);
                    file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                write();
                sudo(ipfetch, netmaskfetch, gatewayfetch, dns1fetch, dns2fetch);
return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                finish();  
            }
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
```

ON Button Click :

```
submt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validationIP();
            if (var == true) {

                 new AsyncAboutUs().execute();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for showing progress dialog is working fine, may be the process is fast and thats why the progress dialog is not visible.
can try using a thread sleep to actually see if there is an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

It does show the progress but you hide it immediately by calling dismiss() and further by finish().

However, doing your heavy task inside the handler is an incorrect way to achieve what you want. It  would not work as you think anyway. What will happen is that your code will block UI thread inside handler and no progress will be shown (and application will potentially be killed if you hold long enough).

The correct way to do this is to implement an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), there is a straightforward code example in this documentation link. You need to show() progress dialog, execute the async task, perform your file etc. code in doInBackground() and update progress values by publishProgress on the way. 
In the onProgressUpdate(), update the dialog or required fields and, finally, in onPostExecute do the finish() or other actions you wish on completion.